# Wordpress - Query if a custom post type has any posts - from outside the loop

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, custom-post-type

I'm making a restaurant menu using custom post types for the different menu sections. I used the excellent Custom Post Types UI plugin and the Verve Meta Boxes plugin. I'm then flowing them out into separate loops with several segments of the below code:

```
    <?php 
   $hotfood = get_posts( array('post_type' => 'hotfood', 'posts_per_page' => -1) );
    foreach ($hotfood as $post) : 
      setup_postdata($post);
   ?>
   <dl>
    <dt>
     <strong><?php the_title_attribute(); ?></strong>
     <span>&pound;<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', true) ?></span>
    </dt>
   <?php
   $key = 'description';
   $themeta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, TRUE);
   if($themeta != '') {
   echo '<dd>'.$themeta.'</dd>';
   }
   ?>
   </dl>
```

But then above that, I'm trying to get an `if` asking whether there are any posts within a custom post type that I've defined.

I've tried things like

```
     <?php if(get_posts ('post_type' => 'hotfood')
  echo '<h2>Hot Food</h2>';
     ?>
```

and

```
  <?php $args = array
   (
   'post_type' => 'hotfood',
   'numberposts' => -1'
   );

   $hotfoodpresent = get_posts($args);

    if($hotfoodpresent) echo '<h2>Hot Food</h2>';
  ?>
```

but neither of those seem to work. I think I've trawled through the Wordpress Codex and have spent quite a lot of time trying to decipher the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
Sorry, totally sorted. I was overcomplicating things. A simple

```
<?php
$hotfoodpresent = get_posts( 
    [
        'post_type' => 'hotfood', 
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'fields' => 'ids'
    ] 
);

if ($hotfoodpresent) {
    echo '<h2>Hot Food</h2>'
};
```

worked perfectly.

Comment: if the get_posts is working for you in your current code, can you add if(isset($hotdogfood)) after that line?

Comment: Oops. I think I was overcomplicating things.

A simple

<?php 
     $hotfoodpresent = get_posts( array('post_type' => 'hotfood', 'posts_per_page' => -1) );
      if($hotfoodpresent) echo '<h2>Hot Food</h2>';
 ?>
worked fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was overcomplicating things. A simple

```
<?php
$hotfoodpresent = get_posts( 
    [
        'post_type' => 'hotfood', 
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'fields' => 'ids'
    ] 
);

if ($hotfoodpresent) {
    echo '<h2>Hot Food</h2>';
};
```

worked perfectly.

Comment: Prefect answer @Magnakai. Thanks

Comment: This is actually not recommended performance-wise,  You may just use the post per page as 1, and return just the id to check ..with 'field'=> 'id' arg

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla, great suggestions. I've updated the code snippet to reflect those performance improvements, and also to improve the formatting.